# How to covert c# code into vb.net (Linq)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

var result = from с in dal.context.Funds 
             select new 
             {
               Name = c.CODE
               Price = c.Price
             };

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big VB user, but something like:

```
Dim result = From c In dal.context.Funds _
                 Select c.CODE, c.Price
```

To rename it, you might need `With` (at a guess):

```
Select New With {.Name = c.CODE, .Price = c.Price}
```

Comment: maybe because you have plenty of points :) ... downvote should always follow a comment in my opinion :/

Comment: Thanks it was helpfull, I'm new here, and I'm not registered yet, As a I will done I'l vote
Also if I want to rename column name to smth like this "Name with spaces"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that VB won't let you do that (the naming thing). Very odd about the downvote - I know it wasn't you, since (as you say) not enough rep to vote yet! I must have annoyed somebody in the past... gotta love vendetta voting. Never mind ;-p If it fixes the problem, click the tick ;-p

Answer (score 0):

I have done language conversion using [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) in the past.

[This](http://diditwith.net/2007/09/24/UsingReflectorToExploreLINQ.aspx) post shows it can help with LINQ as well...